# Accessing request parameters which are not from <form> in RESTful web services

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, rest

I am trying to get request parameters in POST method of REST service. But I am getting null value.  I have tried different techniques using `@FormParam` and `request.getParameter("message")` but with no success. I have used jQuery AJAX for the client:

```
$("#temp1").click(function () {
    var MSG = $("#temp1").attr('href');

   var JSONObject = {"message":MSG};
    var dataString = JSON.stringify(JSONObject); 
    $.ajax
    ({

    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/GetSomeRest/webresources/getfile/1",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: dataString,
            dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
        success: function (data) {

            var msg_data = data;
            $(msg_data).appendTo("#content");
            $('#buttn').show();

        }
```

Web service method:

```
@Path("1")
        @POST
        @Consumes("application/json")
        @Produces("text/plain")
        public String postHtml(@FormParam("message") String file)throws IOException{

         System.out.println(file); //producing null
    }
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<a id="temp1" href="D:/folder/file" >Click Here</a>
<div id='content' style="width:640px; margin-left:450px" contenteditable="true"></div>
<button id="buttn" style="position:relative; margin-top:-960px; margin-left:80%; display:block; float:left">Save</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Why can't you stick with JSON or XML request body for REST API's. Why www-form-urlencoded mode?

Comment: I am new to web services. recently in my organization they told me to implement it on some of the functionalists.  Here i need to pass single parameter (file path) so I thought that I can use www-form-urlencoded mode instead of json/xml. Any way thanks for suggestion I will try it

Comment: Hi I have used json request body, still I ma getting null in web service. Please somebody give me an example. I have updated my code above

Comment: Refer [http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-formparam-example/](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-formparam-example/)

Comment: "http://localhost:8080/GetSomeRest/webresources/getfile/1" is this the the correct URL supposed to call `postHtml()`? Try defining route like "/webresources/getfile/{fileName}" in `postHtml(string fileName)`. In javascript construct the url like `"http://localhost:8080/GetSomeRest/webresources/getfile/" + $("#temp1").attr('href')` in ajax call.